# Problems with showing right colors

Tags: windows, colors, coreldraw

I'm using Corel Draw X6 on Samsung SyncMaster P2370HD. When I open some CDR drawing, colors are not displayed properly on the monitor. E.g. HEX code for white is not `#FFF`, but `#FFFCDB` (I've made screenshot and check the color code in Photoshop). I think there is a problem with some options, maybe it is set to use default display mode. Also, when I export some image, the same problem is in Windows Photo Viewer, but it looks "normally" in Photoshop (white is still white, not yellow). Is there any options in Corel Draw to change this display mode?

Comment: I have seen similar issues solved using the "Calibrate color" feature in windows display settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Opening [Calibrate color wizard](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/calibrate-your-display) in Control Panel and changing gamma properites. White is now really white. :)